# Move database from a filesystem to another without mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I broke a server which had mysql data inside it. I can still access the old server's filesystem but I can't run anything anymore on it. How can I extract my data out of this filesystem to move it to another server? As far as I understand, mysqldump requires a running mysql server to extract the data so I can't use it.

Comment: look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659782/where-is-the-actual-data-in-a-mysql-db-stored-on-a-linux-machine

Comment: If you're using MyISAM it's just as matter of copying the files from the data directory

Comment: but what about with innodb and other engines?

Answer (score 0):

In the target machine set up an empty database with the same name. Now copy the files for the database from the data folder of the dead machine to the data folder on the new machine.

The files will be all the .frm, .MYI, and .MYD files in the folder for the database. It will be in .../mysql/data/myDatabaseName